# Using session variables in Facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I build a simple application available at: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=216798445011521

About The Application:
the application allow you to create in your fan page a "before & after" user like the page and show him a html content.

I have a little question:
I want to upgrade it to a little more tricky but the problem is when you click at index.php on link that redirect the user to about.php my script lose the variable example: if the user is admin or not, if he fan or not, page id etc'

there is an option to fix it? maybe the canvas url force him to support at multi application page or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loosing variable? Probably you should store that kind of data in session, on the server side.

If you do that app in PHP take a look here http://php.net/manual/pl/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

Store all the necessary variables in $_SESSION, so that you can simply access them through out the session.